# Linq и большая база данных Count

Tags: c#, linq

Не могe решить проблему с подсчетом размера коллекции. Есть таблица на сайте с фильтрами, там выводиться 10 записей.

```
 data = dc.books.OrderBy(x => x.id).Where(x =>
                                 (market_id == 0 || x.market_id != 0 && x.market_id == market_id)
                                 && (name == null || x.name != null && (x.name.StartsWith(name)))
                                 && (author == null || x.author != null && (x.author.StartsWith(author)))
                                 ).Skip(param.Start).Take(10).ToList();
```

Все быстро и хорошо работает. Ну мне нужно подсчитать размер полученной коллекции.

```
               count = db.books.Count(x =>
                (market_id == 0 || x.market_id != 0 && x.market_id == market_id)
                && (name == null || x.name != null && (x.name.StartsWith(name)))
```

При одном условии все работает быстро, но стоит мне добавить два других условия, как все вешается. База на Mysql  ~ 500 000. Ка мне решить эту задачу , пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: для начала, я бы выкинул из условий избыточные сравнения. например (market_id == 0 || x.market_id != 0 && x.market_id == market_id) эквивалентно (market_id == 0 || x.market_id == market_id) так как вы используете операцию сокращенных вычислений ||

Answer (score 3):

1. Сделайте составной запрос - сначала сделайте легкую выборку на основные фильтры, а потом в результате сделайте фильтр по x.name.StartsWith(name)
   Именно этот запрос нагружает MySql. Уменьшив набор данных для его работы вы облегчите задачу для сервера.
2. Попробуйте прямой SQL запрос.

Comment: Прямой запрос это правильно, linq2sql конечно удобно, но дико медленно, особенно на больших наборах данных.